# Updating child value to Firebase iOS and referencing auto ID in other nodes

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this structure in mind to write data to Firebase server. However i am having complications in the actual code to write the structure this way.

The part i am confused on is getting the autoID (-LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N) as a reference for all_images and all_plan_deatils nodes. I cannot figure out the best way to write this code out. Any suggestions would greatly help. Thank you in advance

```
PlanIt
 plans
  -LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N
    Uid: "ZjtJdkjzuxc0mZn4u9TfWsXa9jh2"
    date: "20180609"
    title: "This weekend Plans?"
  -UYijs09as9jiosdijfi
    Uid: "some uid"
    date: "20180609"
    title: "some title"

 all_images:
    -LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N
       image_0: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.c.."
       image_1: "https://img.evbuc.com/https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.evbuc.c.."

 all_plan_details
    -LETR-XJvQsZCOpG-T1N
       detail_0: "Bike Rodeo, Safety Presentation and Riding Tour o"
       detail_1: "Bike Rodeo, Safety Presentation and Riding Tour o"
```

- UPDATE

this is the function where i am attempting to update nodes. My thought process here is - I first set the plan title and UID to be created as an Auto Id. i then attempt to reference the "key" that was created by the auto ID, then i try to store all_images & all_dates to be stored with a reference to the same key that was created by the childByAutoID call, and then i update those values.

Sorry for any mess or confusion within the code, i am literally editing things as we speak so certain names and such may be off, but i hope you can understand the general idea of what i am trying to attempt still.

```
func uploadPlanitData(plan: [String], withDate: [String], withImage: [String], withTitle: String, forUID uid: String, sendComplete: @escaping (_ status: Bool) -> ()) {


    _REF_PLANITS.childByAutoId().updateChildValues(["Planit Title" : withTitle, "uid": uid])


    let key = _REF_PLANITS.key

    let allImages = "all_images/\(key)/"

    let allDates = "all_dates/\(key)"

    let childUpdate = [allImages : withImage, allDates: withDate]
    _REF_ALL_IMAGES.updateChildValues(childUpdate)

    sendComplete(true)
}
```

UPDATE - that block of code currently structures my DB like this- which is ALMOST correct - except within the all_images & all_dates nodes , instead of "planits" - im expecting to have that key (-LEaaZrwYI_SqonuREV9) there. That way i have a way to uniquely group each image and date with the plan they belong to

```
Planit
 Plans  
    -LEaaZrwYI_SqonuREV9
     senderId
     title: 


all_dates
 planits
 0: ""

 all_images
 planits
 0: ""
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the code that you've already tried. If you haven't tried anything yet, I recommend looking at a few other questions about [querying Firebase in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bfirebase-database%5d%5bswift%5d%20query).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen will update question now with code I am currently trying. Give me about 2 minutes, thanks

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated now. I hope you can understand what i am trying to get accomplished. Sorry for the confusion, i am knee deep currently within a pool of code so some things may seem off because im adding/reworking code as we speak. Thank you

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen updated my question for more clarity

Comment: Every time you call `childByAutoId` it generates a new unique value. So `_REF_PLANITS.childByAutoId().updateChildValues` sounds very unusual, since you're update child values of a child node you just generated. Are you trying to update an existing plan? If so, do you know the key of the existing plan? If not, what *do* you know of the existing plan?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen my reasoning for calling childByAudoId on the first line, is because that line creates a new "post" every time, so i assumed that each post should carry its own auto ID. So to answer your question, i am not trying to update existing plan with that call, rather set a new plan with a unique key. Now for the line below that, i want to store all images and dates, sorted by those unique keys, so that i have a way to group everything when i am reading the data

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes, you understood perfectly. You also translated it perfectly. Now i see where i skipped a simple step. Thank you for the clarity. You bridged a great gap for me to understand it. I appreciate your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to create new key for a new plan, and then store information in other nodes with the same key. If that is the case, it'd look like this:

```
let newPlanetRef = _REF_PLANITS.childByAutoId()
newPlanetRef.updateChildValues(["Planit Title" : withTitle, "uid": uid])

let key = newPlanetRef.key

let childUpdate = [allImages : withImage, allDates: withDate]
_REF_ALL_IMAGES.child(key).updateChildValues(childUpdate)
```

This assumes that `_REF_PLANITS` is a `DatabaseReference` to `/PlanIt/plans` and `_REF_ALL_IMAGES` is a reference to `/PlanIt/all_images`.

Comment: Yes, you understood perfectly. You also translated it perfectly. Now i see where i skipped a simple step. Thank you for the clarity. You bridged a great gap for me to understand it. I appreciate your time